# Solving a set of linear congruences

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to understand group theory and conguences. I have a question on simultaneous congruences and i have a solution but i do not understand it.

I want to solve the following set of simultaneous congruences:

$x \equiv 5(mod 6) $,  $x \equiv 4(mod 11)$,  $ x \equiv 3(mod 17) $

So i have the solution as $ x = 5 \times 187 \times 1 + 4 \times 102 \times 4 + 3 \times 66 \times 8 = 4151(\mod 1122) = 785 $

But i have no idea how they have got this and cannot find any useful information of simultaneous congruences.

Could someone please show me step by step how to get this answer?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The Chinese Remainder Theorem asserts that the system is solvable and has a unique solution modulo $6\times 11 \times 17 = 1122$. What this solution does is to effectively construct a basis system for the congruence system.

Suppose we can find an integer $e_6$ such that $e_6$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $6$ and congruent to $0$ modulo $11$ and $17$. Suppose that we can find analogous numbers $e_{11}$ and $e_{17}$. These numbers serve the same purpose for our system as the standard basis vectors in linear algebra in that they span the set of solutions. Indeed you can verify that the congruence system
$$x\equiv a \pmod 6$$
$$x\equiv b \pmod{11}$$
$$x\equiv c \pmod{17}$$
will be solved by
$$x= ae_6 + be_{11} + ce_{17}$$
A method like this is particularly useful when you need to solve multiple systems of congruences over the same moduli. You only need to find your $e_i$s once and you can construct appropriate solutions easily.

The problem now lies in actually finding each $e_i$. Let us first find $e_6$ as an example. First we want $11$ and $17$ to be factors of $e_6$ since we require $e_6 \equiv 0 \pmod{11,17}$. So we can write $e_6 = 187k$ and we require the third condition
$$e_6 \equiv 187k \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod{6}$$
We got lucky here in that $187\equiv 1\pmod 6$ but the general solution will require solving a linear congruence. It follows that we can take $e_6 = 187$ and the first term of our sum is then $5e_6 = 5\times 187$, precisely what your solution has.

If we proceed to find $e_{11}$, then we require $6$ and $17$ to be factors. Therefore we can write $e_{11}$ as $e_{11} = 102k$. This means we need to solve
$$e_{11} \equiv 102k \equiv 3k \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$$
The solution to this congruence is $k\equiv 4$ which is why your answer has the second term of the sum as $4e_{11} = 4\times 102 \times 4$.

You can continue the procedure to find $e_{17}$ and you should find that the answer matches what your solution has. In general, this method can be extended to solve any system of congruences (with coprime moduli of course) by finding the appropriate "basis" numbers. In fact, this is one of the ways to prove the Chinese Remainder Theorem in general.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, much clearer now :)

Answer (score 0):

$x\equiv3\pmod{17}$
$x=3+17s$
$3+17s\equiv4\pmod{11}$
$3+6s\equiv4\pmod{11}$
$6s\equiv1\pmod{11}$
$12s\equiv2\pmod{11}$
$s\equiv2\pmod{11}$
$s=2+11t$
$x=3+17s=3+17(2+11t)=37+187t$
$37+187t\equiv5\pmod6$
$1+t\equiv5\pmod6$
$t\equiv4\pmod6$
$t=4+6u$
$x=37+187t=37+187(4+6u)=785+1122u$
$x\equiv785\pmod{1122}$

Comment: i have the sol as 4151(mod 1122) is this the same? thanks!

Comment: Sorry ignore that its fine. Thanks so much for your answer, much clearer now :)